# OS X - Keypress in an if statement

Tags: c++, macos

I am quite new to C++ programming and using Mac as a computer.
I've been searching around the internet for a while now but I can't still find a good solution for my problem.

I am making a project with the Keyboard Arrows, but I don't know how to make the Keypress function in an if statement.

So the solution I am searching for is:

```
if (up arrow is pressed) {
    std::cout << it worked! << std::endl;
}
```

Information:
LLVM Compiler, Xcodes command line tool, Unix, OS X-Sierra
Thank you for the help.

Comment: We'll need to know more about the environment. Is this a OS X GUI application, a CLI tool, an SDL application, or something else?

Comment: Alright wait...

Comment: Are you using `curses` for screen control? If so, the answer is in the docs for `curses`. If not, the answer is harder http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html

Comment: No I am apparently not using any cursers for screen control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I couldn't get the code in the other answer to work, not sure what's different since I'm also running Sierra. But I converted it to using tcsetattr. The point of that call is to put the terminal in raw mode, such that it sends key presses directly. If you don't do that it won't send anything until you press enter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct termios savemodes;
static int havemodes = 0;

int tty_break(void)
{
    struct termios modmodes;
    if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &savemodes) < 0)
        return -1;
    havemodes = 1;
    modmodes = savemodes;
    cfmakeraw(&modmodes);
    return tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &modmodes);
}

int tty_getchar(void)
{
    return getchar();
}

int tty_fix(void)
{
    if(!havemodes)
        return 0;
    return tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &savemodes);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    if(tty_break() != 0)
        return 1;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf(" = %d\n", tty_getchar());
    tty_fix();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine on my Sierra too! I don't use the `Xcode`, which maybe explains the difference - I just use the command-line compiler with `gcc` or `clang` in the Terminal. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I have put the code [which I linked to in the comments](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html) together into a single program so you can see how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sgtty.h>

static struct sgttyb savemodes;
static int havemodes = 0;

int tty_break()
{
    struct sgttyb modmodes;
    if(ioctl(fileno(stdin), TIOCGETP, &savemodes) < 0)
        return -1;
    havemodes = 1;
    modmodes = savemodes;
    modmodes.sg_flags |= CBREAK;
    return ioctl(fileno(stdin), TIOCSETN, &modmodes);
}

int tty_getchar()
{
    return getchar();
}

int tty_fix()
{
    if(!havemodes)
        return 0;
    return ioctl(fileno(stdin), TIOCSETN, &savemodes);
}

main()
{
    int i;
    if(tty_break() != 0)
        return 1;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf(" = %d\n", tty_getchar());
    tty_fix();
    return 0;
}
```

You can compile it simply with:

```
clang main.c -o main
```

and run it with:

```
./main
```

You will see that the <kbd>↑</kbd> (Up Arrow) key causes the following codes:

```
27 (Escape)
91
65
```

Note the code is not mine - it is entirely extracted from the C-FAQ I mentioned above.

Comment: I don't think this works on OS X, there one should be using tcsetattr. Also, I wouldn't recommend to use K&R style code.

Comment: @PerJohansson Thank you for your thoughts.  It runs fine on my copy of Sierra. There may well be alternatives - feel free to add an answer - the more the merrier!

Comment: Weird, I'm also running Sierra, and I can't get it to work. Typed up a tcsetattr version.

Comment: Ok, it works if I add `-DUSE_OLD_TTY` to compiler flags in Xcode. Probably by default Xcode uses a precompiled header including <sys/ioctl.h> which makes the <sgtty.h> include not work.